# How can I check if an appearance property has been set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is there a way to check if a property has been set on an UIAppearance proxy or not?

Let's say I want to do something like:

```
self.lineWidth = appearance.lineWidth ? : kDefaultLineWidth;
```

This will not work correctly if the lineWidth was set to zero on the proxy since it would be indistinguishable from not having been set at all (assuming it's a CGFloat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make that check; the appearance system will take care of it for you. In your initialiser, set `lineWidth` to your default value *using direct ivar access* instead of its setter:

```
_lineWidth = kDefaultLineWidth;
```

If an appearance property has been set for `lineWidth`, this will be overridden. If not, it will not be overridden.

The problem arises when you instead set `lineWidth` *via its setter*. The appearance system will then mark that instance as having been customised, and won't override your change.

Source: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/uiappearance-for-custom-views/

> One gotcha is that UIAppearance swizzles all setters that have a default apperance, and tracks when they get changed, so that UIAppearance doesn’t override your customizations. [If] we use setters in the initializer, ...for UIAppearance it now looks as though we already customized the class ourselves. Lesson: Only use *direct ivar access* in the initializer for properties that comply to UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.